# box-shadow is not getting applied for table header

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component

I tried to make changes to the following CSS to add border-bottom to the header component but it is not working. I have also tried adding a border.  Any leads to solving this is appreciated.

In the inspect element in chrome all the header elements are crossed out.

[image]

The rows have the borderline but the header doesn't have a line.

```css
.app-tableSF {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: $primary-black-lighten1;
  background: $primary-white;
  &__body {
    height: calc(100% - 78px);
  }
  &__header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 0 0 #ededed;
    border-bottom: thick;
    & > div {
      height: 32px !important;
      text-align: left !important;
      text-transform: capitalize !important;
      font-weight: 600 !important;
      font-size: 1em !important;
      color: #B9BABD !important;
      white-space: nowrap !important;
      opacity: 1 !important;
      cursor: default !important;
      transition: all $animation-duration linear !important;
    }
  }
  &__row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px -1px 0 0 #ededed;
    & > div {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      height: 40px;
      padding: 0 8px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      width: 100%;
      &:first-child {
        margin-left: 28px;
      }
      &:last-child {
        margin-right: 28px;
      }
    }
  }
  &__message {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: $secondary-gray-darken1;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  &--no-header {
    .app-table__header {
      height: 0px;
    }
    .app-table__body {
      height: 100%;
    }
  }
  .vb-dragger {
    left: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div :class="['app-tableSF', { 'app-tableSF--no-header': !tableFields}]">
    
    <div :class="['app-tableSF__row','app-tableSF__header']">
      <div
        :class="cellClasses[index]"
        v-for="(field, index) in tableFields"
        :key="index"
      >{{ field.label }}</div>
    </div>
    
    <div
      class="app-tableSF__body"
      v-bar
      ref="tBody"
    >
    
      <div
        @scroll="onScroll"
        ref="scrollContainer"
      >
        <p
          class="app-tableSF__message"
          v-if="!pending && (!data || !data.length)"
        >{{ message }}</p>
        <div
          class="app-tableSF__row-wrapper"
          v-for="row in data"
          :key="row.id"
        >
          <div :class="['app-tableSF__row', rowClass(row)]">
            <slot
              :row="row"
              :cellClasses="cellClasses"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: post HTML as well

Comment: it is actually a  vuejs component

Comment: target table header `th` rather then table header itself

Answer (score 1):

Add style to `th` in your table header, You are targeting selector is wrong(you are targeting table no its elements)

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th{
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>head</th><th>head</th><th>head</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>body</td><td>body</td><td>body</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css select the th/td elements inside the header and style them, not the header itself.

```
.app-tableSF {
// ...
  &__header {
    td, th { 
      border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    }
  }
}
```